# python set element in dict by accessing non-existent element

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to add a new element to dictionary this way:

```python3
d["key1"]["key2"]["key3"] = 10
```

But I have to do it such way:

```python3
d["key1"] = {}
d["key1"]["key2"] = {}
d["key1"]["key2"]["key3"] = 10
```

Because otherwise I will encounter `KeyError`. 
Is there any options to add new element in more elegant way?

**UPD**
Actually my code contains such new elements assigning:

```python3
d["key1"]["key2"]["key3"] = 10
d["key1"]["key2"]["key4"]["key5"] = 15
d["key6"]["key7"]["key8"]["key9"]["key10"] = 20
```

So it seems that declaring `defaultdict` with constructor in such way:

```python3
d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: ""))
```

will not work because amount acceses of dict is not predetermined.

Comment: Can you use `COllections` if so `from collections import defaultdict`

Comment: yes, I can use collections, but it seems that in case of defaultdict usage, I will have to write something with recursive defaultdict constructor like `d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: ""))` but it 1) is ugly 2) will break when i will try to add new element in such way: `d["key1"]["key2"]["key3"]["key4"] = 10`

Answer (score 4):

***Other Solution Using Function***

You can create a function to add elements to a nested dictionary

```py
def add_to_nested_dict(d, keys, value):
    for key in keys[:-1]:
        if key not in d:
            d[key] = {}
        d = d[key]
    d[keys[-1]] = value

my_dict = {}
add_to_nested_dict(my_dict, ["key1", "key2", "key3", "key4"], 10)
print(my_dict)
```

output:

```
{'key1': {'key2': {'key3': {'key4': 10}}}}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `collections.defaultdict` without encountering KeyError for each level of nesting.

Here's update code:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int)))
d["key1"]["key2"]["key3"] = 10
```

Comment: Is there more common solution? e.g. after definition of `d` as `defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int)))`, I will try to `d["key1"]["key2"]["key3"]["key4"] = 10` and it seems that it will break

Comment: @wowonline you can using function

Comment: could you please provide more details about using function in that case?

Comment: @wowonline Yes with pleasure